# git push and rlogin fail when connecting via VPN from home network; from mobile network it is ok

Tags: networking, network-interface, vpn

I connect from a source network to a target network using a VPN. Both networks are home networks provided by DSL routers.

I set up the target network with a different IP address range to have no conflicts between the two networks (the target network machines have an IP address starting with 192.168.17***7***.* - instead of the usual 192.168.17***8***.*).

I am able to ping and traceroute a machine in the target network successfully:

```
$ ping 192.168.177.70
PING 192.168.177.70 (192.168.177.70) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.177.70: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=32.2 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.177.70: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=31.3 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.177.70: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=29.6 ms
...


$ traceroute 192.168.177.70
traceroute to 192.168.177.70 (192.168.177.70), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  this-is-not-a-raspi.fritz.box (192.168.177.70)  34.185 ms  34.184 ms  36.328 ms
 2  this-is-not-a-raspi.fritz.box (192.168.177.70)  36.341 ms  37.337 ms  37.348 ms
$
```

Unfortunately, I cannot push to that server with `git push` or connect via `rlogin`:

```
$ git push --dry-run --verbose
Pushing to pi@192.168.177.70:/usr/local/git/python/myProject
Connection closed by 192.168.177.70 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

---------------

rlogin pi@192.168.177.70
Connection closed by 192.168.177.70 port 22
```

For both commands, it takes some minutes before they get a timeout.

Both commands work properly, when I supply a mobile hot spot from my smartphone with a mobile connection (and use the VPN connection from my local computer as before).

In both situations I can connect to the remote computer when using a RDP connection:

```
xfreerdp /v:192.168.177.70 /u:pi  /f +clipboard
```

**What do I have to do to get `git push` and `rlogin` working when connecting from the home network?**

---

More details (in the following all ip6 and mac addresses should be obfuscated; schema: replace real literals with capital letters A-F where appropriate):

`ip addr` when using the router from the source home network:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:AA:BB:CC:DD:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:AA:BB:CC:DD:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.11/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 604664sec preferred_lft 604664sec
    inet6 2a02:AAAA:BBBB:CCCC::2867/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 43065sec preferred_lft 43065sec
    inet6 2a02:AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:9076/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 86399sec preferred_lft 43199sec
    inet6 2a02:AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:c252/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86399sec preferred_lft 43199sec
    inet6 fe80::DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:365/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1412 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.177.201/24 brd 192.168.177.255 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:4b69/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip addr` when using the mobile hot spot:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:AA:BB:CC:DD:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:AA:BB:CC:DD:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.67.175/24 brd 192.168.67.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 3569sec preferred_lft 3569sec
    inet6 2a02:AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:9076/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 3572sec preferred_lft 3572sec
    inet6 2a02:AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:41bc/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 3572sec preferred_lft 3572sec
    inet6 fe80::DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:41bc/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1412 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 192.168.177.201/24 brd 192.168.177.255 scope global noprefixroute tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:835f/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip addr` on the remote computer (when connected via mobile hot spot):

```
pi@this-is-not-a-raspi:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 88:AA:BB:CC:DD:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.177.70/24 brd 192.168.177.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 598756sec preferred_lft 598756sec
    inet6 fe80::AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:66aa/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp0s20f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:AA:BB:CC:DD:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:AA:BB:CC:DD:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:AA:BB:CC:DD:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
pi@this-is-not-a-raspi:~$
```

`tcdump` for `ssh pi@192.168.177.70` when using the mobile network:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:47:32.226287 IP user-computer.47739 > 77.15.121.102.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xcbf45046,seq=0x4e), length 404
00:47:32.386227 IP6 2a02:AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:9076.49668 > fra07s63-in-x2005.1e100.net.https: Flags [FP.], seq 3522424528, ack 2611353171, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 1460897741 ecr 3651489834], length 0
00:47:32.386256 IP6 2a02:AAAA:BBBB:CCCC:DDDD:EEEE:FFFF:9076.60320 > fra24s11-in-x0e.1e100.net.https: Flags [FP.], seq 720768930:720769032, ack 218366535, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 642136371 ecr 1993197571], length 102
00:47:32.391786 IP6 user-computer.40601 > fra24s11-in-x0e.1e100.net.443: UDP, length 1226

4 packets captured
191 packets received by filter
3 packets dropped by kernel
```

`tcdump` when using the home router:

[pastebin link for tcdump with home router](https://pastebin.com/ZemURvzv)